# why am i getting a 404 error at Tomcat 8.5.85 *.war deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to deploy a simple spring boot project on tomcat server.

Locally via Intellij IDEA everything is working.

This is my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/spring-mvc")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String homePage() {
        return "<p style='color: green;'>Hello, World</p>";
    }
}
```

This is my Main Class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.visionthing</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-mvc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I exported the war via maven cli and moved it to the /webapps folder of my tomcat installation.

tomcat is running openjdk 19 as well as my local project.

When opening tomcat webui manager the folder shows up, clicking on it redirects me to http://localhost:8081/spring-mvc/ this site displays the 404 error page of tomcat.
as well as
http://localhost:8081/spring-mvc/index
http://localhost:8081/spring-mvc/spring-mvc/index

I was expecting to see Hello, World written in green on http://localhost:8081/spring-mvc/index

did i forget something?

thanks in regard.

i'm running linux pop-os based on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: 1. Why port 8081 ? Have you changed Tomcat settings?  2. What is your war file name ? 3. please show your `pom.xml`

Comment: Yes I changed tomcat configs, so the tomcat server doesn't collide with local tests from intellij IDEA wich run on port 8080. War File name is spring-mvc.war I will add pom.xml

Comment: Can Tomcat be replaced with another version?

Comment: Can you change the version of Spring Boot? Is it mandatory that Spring Boot must be 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mini spring boot war for spring boot 2.7.8

## Project Directory

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── visionthing
        │           └── springmvc
        │               ├── HomeController.java
        │               └── SpringMvcApplication.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── application.properties
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── jsp
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <!--<version>3.0.2</version>-->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.visionthing</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>spring-mvc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## SpringMvcApplication.java

```
package com.visionthing.springmvc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMvcApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringMvcApplication.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## HomeController.java

```
package com.visionthing.springmvc;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/spring-mvc")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String homePage() {
        return "<p style='color: green;'>Hello, World</p>";
    }
}
```

## application.properties (optional)

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

## package

```
mvn clean package
```

put spring-mvc.war to tomcat/webapps

start tomcat

## test

command line test: `curl http://localhost:8081/spring-mvc/spring-mvc/index`

browser test open : `http://localhost:8081/spring-mvc/spring-mvc/index`

## conclusion

Why I am change spring boot to 2.7.8 ?

Because you can test the same project and the same code , just change pom.xml

Spring boot version to 3.0.2 , and re-package war , you will get 404 again.

Spring Boot 3.x require JDK 17 , but your pom.xml set source and target to version `1.8`.

Spring Boot 3.x require Tomcat 10.x , but you use Tomcat 8.x.

So I can only provide a minimum example project that can be executed, for your limitation Tomcat 8.x, source and target is set to 1.8.

In addition, I removed irrelevant dependencies in pom.xml.

---

## UPDATE For Spring Boot 3.0.2

1. Change `pom.xml`,

- spring boot version to 3.0.2
- remove compiler configuration : source , target 1.8

2. Change Tomcat

- Use Tomcat 10.x

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.7.8</version>-->
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.visionthing</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>spring-mvc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Tomcat 10.x

Comment: thanks, i got it running using tomcat 10 and spring 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `Main.class` to `application.sources(HomeController.class)` instead of `HomeController.class`. Like this:
`application.sources(Main.class)`.

Comment: Thanks, i changed that although it did not solve my problem :)